# Does there exist a solution that satisfies these conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification

Suppose that

- $i\geq 2$
- $j\geq 4$
- $k\geq 6$
- $x_a,y_a$ for $a=1,2,\ldots,k$ are positive constants with $x_a\leq y_a$ for each $a=1,\ldots,k$.

Is there some $(x_1,\ldots,x_k,y_1,\ldots,y_k)$ with $0<x_a<y_a$ for all $a=1,2,\ldots,k$ satisfying the following $2k$ conditions?

$$
\begin{cases}\prod_{b=i+1}^jy_b\leqslant y_a\prod_{b=1,\atop b\neq a}^i x_b, & 1\leqslant a\leqslant i\\
\prod_{b=1}^iy_b+\prod_{b=j+1}^ky_b\leqslant y_a\prod_{b=i+1,\atop b\neq a}^jx_b, & i+1\leqslant a\leqslant j\\
\prod_{b=i+1}^j y_b\leqslant y_a\prod_{b=j+1,\atop b\neq a}^k x_b, & j+1\leqslant a\leqslant k
    \end{cases},
$$
$$
\begin{cases}\prod_{b=i+1}^jx_b\geqslant x_a\prod_{b=1,\atop b\neq a}^i y_b, & 1\leqslant a\leqslant i\\\prod_{b=1}^i x_b+\prod_{b=j+1}^k x_b\geqslant x_a\prod_{b=i+1,\atop b\neq a}^j y_b, & i+1\leqslant a\leqslant j\\\prod_{b=i+1}^j x_b\geqslant x_a\prod_{b=j+1,\atop b\neq a}^k y_b, & j+1\leqslant a\leqslant k.\end{cases}
$$

**EDIT**: I am pretty sure, no such solution exists. Here is my proof for which I would like to get some verification.

Proof. Suppose $(x_1,\ldots,x_k,y_1,\ldots,y_k)$ with $0<x_a<y_a$ for all $a=1,\ldots,k$ satisfied the conditions above.  Choose $a\in\{i+1,\ldots,j\}$ and $c\in\{1,\ldots,i\}$. Then, on the one hand,
$$
\prod_{b=1}^iy_b+\prod_{b=j+1}^ky_b\leq y_a\prod_{b=i+1,\atop b\neq a}^j x_b\leq y_a\prod_{b=i+1,\atop b\neq a}^j y_b=\prod_{b=i+1}^jy_b\tag{1}
$$
and, on the other hand,
$$
\prod_{b=i+1}^j y_b\leq y_c\prod_{b=1,\atop b\neq a}^i x_b\leq y_c\prod_{b=1,\atop b\neq a}^i y_b=\prod_{b=1}^iy_b\leq\prod_{b=1}^iy_b+\prod_{b=j+1}^ky_b.\tag{2}
$$
Combining (1) and (2), all the inequalities are in fact equalities. In particular, one gets
$$
y_a\prod_{b=i+1,\atop b\neq a}^j x_b=y_a\prod_{b=i+1,\atop b\neq a}^j y_b.
$$
Dividing by $y_a>0$,
$$
\prod_{b=i+1,\atop b\neq a}^j x_b = \prod_{b=i+1,\atop b\neq a}^j y_b.
$$
But this contradicts $0<x_a<y_a$ for all $a=1,\ldots,k$.

Some proof verification (or alternative ideas) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to have a look on your proof first, and then show my proof.

(This answer assumes that $j-i\geqslant 2$ and $k-j\geqslant 2$ are also given.)

---

I think your proof is correct.

Using your idea, I would do as follows :

Choosing $a\in\{i+1,i+2,\ldots,j\}$, we have
$$
\prod_{b=1}^iy_b+\prod_{b=j+1}^ky_b\leqslant y_a\prod_{b=i+1,\atop b\neq a}^j x_b\color{red}{\lt} y_a\prod_{b=i+1,\atop b\neq a}^j y_b=\prod_{b=i+1}^jy_b\tag3
$$
Choosing $a\in\{1,2,\ldots,i\}$, we have
$$
\prod_{b=i+1}^j y_b\leqslant y_a\prod_{b=1,\atop b\neq a}^i x_b\color{red}{\lt} y_a\prod_{b=1,\atop b\neq a}^i y_b=\prod_{b=1}^iy_b\leqslant\prod_{b=1}^iy_b+\prod_{b=j+1}^ky_b.\tag4
$$

This is a contradiction.$\ \blacksquare$

---

In the following, I'm going to write my proof.

I think your idea is better than mine.

Suppose that there is an $a\in\{1,2,\ldots, i\}$ such that

$$x_a\prod_{b=1,\atop b\neq a}^i y_b\geqslant y_a\prod_{b=1,\atop b\neq a}^i x_b$$

Then, we have
$$\prod_{b=i+1}^jx_b\geqslant x_a\prod_{b=1,\atop b\neq a}^i y_b\geqslant y_a\prod_{b=1,\atop b\neq a}^i x_b\geqslant \prod_{b=i+1}^jy_b$$
which implies
$$\prod_{b=i+1}^jx_b\geqslant \prod_{b=i+1}^jy_b$$
which is impossible since $0<x_a<y_a$ for all $a=1,\cdots,k$.

So, we can say that for all $a\in\{1,2,\ldots, i\}$,
$$x_a\prod_{b=1,\atop b\neq a}^i y_b\lt y_a\prod_{b=1,\atop b\neq a}^i x_b\tag5$$

Let $z_a:=\frac{x_a}{y_a}$ and $Z:=\prod_{b=1}^{i}z_b$. Then, $(5)$ can be written as $z_a^2\lt Z$. So, we get
$$Z^2=z_1^2z_2^2\cdots z_i^2\lt Z^i$$

Since $0\lt Z\lt 1$, we have $2\gt i$ which is impossible.$\ \blacksquare$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!